# C Program returns incorrect result

Tags: c, function

I'm making a program to calculate flowrate but everytime you enter in the variables when the program is excecuted, it returns the wrong answer. I got the formula for calculating flow rate from this website "http://www.flowmeterdirectory.com/flowcalculator.php", i'm using it as a a reference to check my program's results but they never work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "PI.h"

int flowRateFormula(int,int);   //Finally, finds out the flow rate
int square(int);        

int square(int x)
{
    x=pow(x,2);

    return x;
}

int flowRateFormula(int pipeDiameter,int velocity)
{
    int integer3=0.25*(PI*square(pipeDiameter)*velocity);

    return integer3;
}

int main()
{
    int flowRate;
    int velocity;
    int pipeDiameter;


    printf("Enter velocity of liquid(in./s):");
    scanf("%d",&velocity);
    printf("Velocity=%d in/s.\n",velocity);

    printf("Enter pipe diameter(inches):");
    scanf("%d",&pipeDiameter);
    printf("Pipe Diameter=%d inches.\n",pipeDiameter);

    printf("Applying formula for Flow Rate.........\n");
    flowRate=flowRateFormula(pipeDiameter,velocity);

    printf("Pipe Diameter=%d inches.\n",pipeDiameter);

    printf("Velocity of liquid=%d in/s.\n",velocity);

    printf("Thus, the flow rate=%d ft/s.\n",flowRate);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ...throw it in a debugger and see what happens?

Comment: Ah, got it. All of your other questions have had the "homework" tag, so you're trying to get us to do your work for you without anyone knowing it's for school. Nice try - didn't work. :)

Comment: Why, oh why, do people use `pow(x,2)` to square a number?

Comment: Why, oh why, do people use the Homework tag lol. Man thats classic...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's most likely because of the integer cast. Depending on your inputs, the results can be close and appear to have the same result because of rounding during the integer cast. Use double in your function instead.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to get a lot of error due to the fact that you're using `int` everywhere. `float` or `double` would be a better choice. This alone could explain why you're getting the same results despite entering different values. For example, `int flow=0.25*x` would give the same value for `flow` for all x where x > -4 and x < 4.

Answer (score 1):

To get accurate result, you need `float` or `double` type.

Please try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double PI = 3.14;

double flowRateFormula(float, float);   

double flowRateFormula(float pipeDiameter, float velocity)
{
    double p = pow(pipeDiameter, 2);
    double result = 0.25 * PI * p * velocity;
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    double flowRate;
    float velocity;
    float pipeDiameter;

    printf("Enter velocity of liquid(in./s):");
    scanf("%f",&velocity);
    printf("Velocity=%f in/s.\n",velocity);

    printf("Enter pipe diameter(inches):");
    scanf("%f",&pipeDiameter);
    printf("Pipe Diameter=%f inches.\n",pipeDiameter);

    printf("Applying formula for Flow Rate.........\n");
    flowRate=flowRateFormula(pipeDiameter,velocity);

    printf("Pipe Diameter=%f inches.\n",pipeDiameter);
    printf("Velocity of liquid=%f in/s.\n",velocity);
    printf("Thus, the flow rate=%f ft/s.\n",flowRate);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./a.out 
Enter velocity of liquid(in./s):10
Velocity=10.000000 in/s.
Enter pipe diameter(inches):20
Pipe Diameter=20.000000 inches.
Applying formula for Flow Rate.........
Pipe Diameter=20.000000 inches.
Velocity of liquid=10.000000 in/s.
Thus, the flow rate=3140.000000 ft/s.
$ 
$ 
$ 
$ 
$ ./a.out 
Enter velocity of liquid(in./s):12.34
Velocity=12.340000 in/s.
Enter pipe diameter(inches):435.345
Pipe Diameter=435.345001 inches.
Applying formula for Flow Rate.........
Pipe Diameter=435.345001 inches.
Velocity of liquid=12.340000 in/s.
Thus, the flow rate=1835912.361516 ft/s.
$
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You are doing floating point arithmetic and returning the result to int.  I would change variables to floats or doubles were needed.